# Null geodesics in the equatorial plane of Schwarzschild geometry

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, computational-physics, geodesics

In Chandrasekhar's [The Mathematical Theory of Black Holes](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-mathematical-theory-of-black-holes-9780198503705?cc=in&lang=en&), the various classes of null geodesics in the equatorial plane of Schwarzschild geometry are as in the following two figures:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

In the figures, the coordinate axes are not mentioned. So, what are coordinate axes in these plots of the geodesics?

Also, I am trying to plot them but couldn't understand how to plot them. Any useful information regarding this would be very helpful.

Comment: Schwarzschild is spherically symmetric, so what difference does it make if it is the equatorial, polar or any other plane?

Comment: @Yukterez Yes, in Schwarzschild geometry they are all the same. But to generalize to Kerr geometry, the equatorial geodesics are more important to study accretion processes.

Comment: @Yukterez Exactly! no physical difference. But believe me, you will impress your audience much more if you say that you are studying exotic equatorial orbits around black holes. Sharks and pirates lurking behind the event horizon... :-)

Comment: They're not in polar/spherical coordinates, you'd never layout perpendicular axes like that and angles certainly don't increase in straight increments with distance (which you can tell its distance because its a trajectory plot for different potential cases. i.e. E > E_min so path curves then escapes, and E < E_min, path in-falls to source. It looks like (scaled) Cartesian axes, a nice 2-D 'x'-'y' plot.

Comment: 1 unit of x and y is 14/3·GM/c², which is obvious from the plot description. For the 2nd question on how to plot that yourself see http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/2.html